# What is this error I get when I try to hash my password in symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, password-hash

This is the error

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder::encodePassword()
>   must be an instance of
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface, instance of
>   App\Entity\User given, called in
>   C:\Users\willi\Desktop\Crowdin\src\Controller\CompteController.php on
>   line 44

CompteController.php :

```
  /** 
 * @Route("/inscriptions", name="inscription")
 */
public function inscriptions(Request $request, ObjectManager $manager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder) {
    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationType::class, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $hash = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword());

        $user->setPassword($hash);

        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
    }

    return $this->render('compte/inscriptions.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

User.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *  fields={"email"},
 *  message="L'email que vous avez indiqué est déja utilisé !"
 * )
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
```

Comment: `App\Entity\User` must either implement `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface` or a descendant interface, or extend a class that does.

Comment: i already do this

Comment: do you want my app\entity\User ?

Comment: Are you sure you implemented the right `UserInterface`? What does `var_dump($user instanceof Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface)` say?

Comment: that say false.

Comment: How did you implement it?

Comment: Use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface in my entity User.php

Comment: There's more to it than that.

Comment: Go ahead and update your question with your User code.  No need to show the whole thing.  Just the class User implements UserInterface line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're only importing the interface into the local namespace, but not actually implementing it.

```
namespace foo;         // namespace declaration
use Bar\UserInterface; // namespace import, does not actually implement it.

class User implements UserInterface { // <- this is the important part
  // now you need to implement the methods specified in the interface.
}
```

Alternatively, assuming class `Bar\User` implements `Bar\UserInterface`:

```
class User extends Bar\User {
  // now you only need to define/redefine the specific things that you want to
}
```